# Como deixar executar uma função após algum tempo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

Tenho um código em javascript ( jquery ) e ele executa uma função quando eu movo o scroll do mouse, porém, ele executa a função várias vezes quando dou uma volta inteira no scroll. Não queria que isso acontecesse, queria que ele só pudesse executar novamente depois de um tempo. Alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer isso?

```js
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        $('.flexhome').flexslider('prev');
        console.log('passa_slide');
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.flexhome').flexslider('next');
        console.log('volta_slide');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Acima ele pega a função prev e next do flexslider, quando eu giro para um lado ele executa o prev, e quando giro para o outro ele executa o next. Porém se girar bastante a bolinha, ele executa o prev ou next várias vezes, passando vários slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisas de uma função que faça debounce, ou seja: evite ser chamada até um certo tempo ter passado desde a ultima chamada.

Eu uso muito isso com eventos de mouse.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

e depois podes usar/chamar assim:

```
var funcaoMagica = debounce(function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        $('.flexhome').flexslider('prev');
        console.log('passa_slide');
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.flexhome').flexslider('next');
        console.log('volta_slide');
        return false;
    }
}, 250);
$(window).bind('mousewheel', funcaoMagica);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo!!! 

Deu certo!!

Obrigado Sergio!!!!

Comment: @BernardoKowacic essas funções são muito úteis. Fico contente de ter ajudado.

Comment: @Sergio, sim, na verdade estou fazendo um site em horizontal, e usei o flexslider para exibir as páginas, apenas tirei a rolagem automática, aí só precisava que o site funcionasse quando eu giro o scroll do mouse haha.